# Jenkins picking old value for Laravel .env

Tags: php, laravel, jenkins

I have created a Jenkins pipeline and shared the stages below. The Jenkins server is hosted on an EC2 instance and the MySQL database is hosted via AWS RDS.

```
stages {
        stage("Build") {
            steps {
               sh 'php --version'
               sh 'composer install'
               sh 'composer --version'
            }
        }
        stage("Unit test") {
            steps {
                sh "sed -i -e 's/\r//g' .env.example"
                sh 'cp .env.example .env'
                sh "sed -i 's/^DB_DATABASE=.*/&${DB_DATABASE}/' .env"
                sh "sed -i 's/^DB_USERNAME=.*/&${DB_USERNAME}/' .env"
                sh "sed -i 's|^DB_HOST=.*|&${DB_HOST}|' .env"
                sh script: $/
                        sed -i 's/^\(DB_PASSWORD=*\).*$/\1"${DB_PASSWORD}"/' .env
                        sed -i 's/^\(APP_ENV=*\).*$/\1"testing"/' .env
                /$
                sh 'php artisan migrate'
                sh 'php artisan test'
            }
        }
```

The problem is that while making a build getting the below error:

```
+ php artisan migrate
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = **** and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

Reason for this is that Jenkins is picking up wrong previous .env value for DB_HOST but inside .env DB_HOST it has the correct value and `php artisan migrate` also works from terminal.

Already executed commands to clear application cache, config:cache etc via terminal.

How to resolve this from Jenkins? Please help.

Comment: How are you setting the DB_DATABASE and other environment variables?

Comment: @ycr - As already shared above, in the Unit Test stage.

Comment: I mean how are they set in Jenkins? Simply the variable ${DB_USERNAME} etc. has to be declared in Jenkins or you should already have it declared in the host system.

Comment: @ycr In Jenkinsfile, already defined the variable like DB_HOST=credentials("DB_HOST") inside environment {}

Comment: Can you do an `echo "$DB_HOST" ` before `sh "sed -i -e 's/\r//g' .env.example"`(Not within) and see whether it's the updated value. Also, what do you mean by this "Jenkins is picking up wrong previous .env value for DB_HOST but inside .env DB_HOST it has the correct value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the solution.

Make sure that the variable name in Jenkinsfile is not similar to the key name of .env.

In my case it was picking up the Jenkinsfile variable name matching up with the .env key instead of the value that I passed.

So, change the `DB_HOST` in Jenkinsfile to `DIFF_DB_HOST` and it's working fine.